# Clear text formatting in Outlook 2016

Tags: ms-office

I am looking for the ribbon button to clear text formatting in Outlook 2016 on Mac and it just doesn't appear to be there.  Am I somehow missing it?  Can I enable it?  Is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no button to clear the text formatting. The fastest way is to cut the text, go to the correct formatting (either manually or by moving the insertion point such as by pressing backspace), then pasting using Edit → Paste and Match Style.